# Can a resample result object be converted to BMR result object in MLR?

Tags: mlr

I want to convert resample result object to BMR result object and combine it with previous BMR result object? This is possible in MLR3 (as_benchmark_result() and $cobmine()) but not sure if it is also possible in MLR

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. This is one of the limitations of the old `mlr` which is now better implemented in `mlr3`.

(If you are missing a feature from `mlr` in `mlr3`, please open an issue in the mlr3 repo on GitHub ️)